# Convert NamedTuple elements to Tensorflow Dataset element type

Tags: python, tensorflow

When a `tf.data.Dataset` is created from builtin/regular Python types (`int`, `float`, `list`, ...) the leaf nodes inside each element of the dataset object are converted to `tf.Tensor` objects.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple, List
import tensorflow as tf

class Coord(NamedTuple):
  x: int
  y: int

class Element(NamedTuple):
  coords: List[Coord]
  kind: int

my_element = Element([Coord(1, 2), Coord(3, 4)], 5)

def iterable_to_generator(iter):
  def generator():
    for element in iter:
      yield element
  return generator

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
  iterable_to_generator([my_element]), output_types=Element(tf.int32, tf.int32))

for element in dataset:
  print(element)

# Prints:
# Element(coords=<tf.Tensor: id=111, shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
# array([[1, 2],
#        [3, 4]])>, kind=<tf.Tensor: id=112, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=5>)
```

Is there a way to convert `my_element` into the same result that is printed in the snippet above (an object of type `Element` with a two `tf.Tensor` objects for `.coords` and `.kind`) 
 without creating a list, a generator, a `tf.data.Dataset` and then extracting the element from the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this using [`tf.convert_to_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) and [`tf.nest.map_structure`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nest/map_structure):

```py
tf.nest.map_structure(tf.convert_to_tensor, my_element)
```